# Expanded sub-labels keep collapsing in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I use a lot of filters in Gmail, which apply various labels and sub-labels to incoming messages.  Normally when I log into Gmail, the labels and sub-labels are exactly as I left them the last time I was logged in, meaning that if **Label 2** is a sub-label of **Label 1** and **Label 1** was expanded so that I could look at messages in **Label 2**, then **Label 1** is still expanded and **Label 2** is still immediately visible the next time I log in.

I like this.

What I don't like is that, for the last month or so, my labels have been collapsing on their own, about once per week, so that only the top-level labels are visible.  In other words, every once and a while the expansion of the labels is *reset*.  For me, this behaviour is *abnormal*.

Why is this happening?  Should I be concerned?  Are there any recent changes in Gmail that explain this?  Has anyone else had this behaviour?

It might only be happening for my mobile browser view, but I can't be certain until the next time that it happens.

Comment: I should add, I don't see anything suspicious in my gmail log-in history.

Comment: I really doubt there's anything nefarious going on here. It's probably just Google neglecting to remember the last state of the label. I, personally, wouldn't count on sub-labels staying expanded if I want to see them all the time. I'd move such labels to the top level.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be related to browser cookies. I expanded labels in one browser and then opened my mailbox in a different browser and they were open. I guess I'll leave them open and see what happens tomorrow.